# regex in datatable search doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

According to https://datatables.net/reference/api/search

I can pass true as second arguemnt and then the search will look after my regex.

I tried this code:

```
var filter = "^111$";    
var filter2 = "Client";
clienttable
.column(15).search(
filter,
true,
false
)
.column(11).search(
filter2,
false,
true
).draw();
```

When I try to use their smart search I got other results, for exmple it returns rows with column 15 of 1112, or any row that includes 111 in column 15.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to only use the 2nd parameter as `true` (and the 3rd as `false`) if you want to use a custom regex for whole string matching. See the description in the docs: *If you wish to use a custom regular expression, for example **to perform whole word exact matching, you would need to enable the regular expression option (second parameter) and disable the smart search option (third parameter)** to ensure that the two do not conflict.*

Comment: its exactly as I passed to the function.

Comment: So, when passing `Client` with smart search, you get all rows containing `Client`, isn't it logical? Don't you get just `111` entries with the first filter? Also, please check [`searchCols`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchCols).

Comment: I don't get any rows with the first filter (111), there are matching rows in the db. About the "Client" is logical. I didn't see the regex search works even once